# got undefined loop through obj array using forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays

I do `console.log(entry.passengers)`
I got this

```
[{"name":"james"},{"name":"john"},{"name":"abc"}]
```

But why I got undefined when I used forEach?

```
entry.passengers.forEach(function(i,obj){
  console.log(obj.name); // undefined
});
```

Comment: What does `console.log(obj)` show?

Comment: Look at the order of arguments to the callback in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: You have been corrupted, the order of parameters passed to the callback is *value*, *index*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first parameter to [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is the element and second parameter is the index.

```
entry.passengers.forEach(function(obj, i) {
//                                ^^^  ^ Change the sequence
```

```js
var arr = [{
  "name": "james"
}, {
  "name": "john"
}, {
  "name": "abc"
}];

arr.forEach(function(e, i) {
  console.log(e, i);

  document.write(e.name + '<br />');
});
```

Comment: so it's opposite of $.each?

Comment: @user3519144 the order of parameters, yes.

Comment: thanks! didn't know that! must be careful next time.

Comment: @user3519144—yes, jQuery has it backwards.